# Set Header using REQUEST_URI and ap_expr in Apache 2.4

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess

I need to set a noindex header for our sitemap.xml page. I can't use a `<meta>` tag, so the other option seems to involve setting a header via Apache.

Additionally, I can't use the `<Files>` directive because our sitemap.xml is generated by PHP and is not a file.

I've tried this, but I don't think `RewriteCond` works in conjunction with `Header` because this is affecting all pages:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/sitemap\.xml$ [NC]
Header set X-Robots-Tag "noindex"
```

This doesn't produce any effect:

```
<If "%{REQUEST_URI} =~ /^sitemap.xml$/">
    Header set X-Robots-Tag "noindex"
</If>
```

It seems like the best option would be to use [ap_expr](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/expr.html), but this doesn't work either:

```
Header set X-Robots-Tag "noindex" "expr=%{REQUEST_URI} =~ m#^/sitemap\.xml$#i"
```

Can someone spot a regex problem? Am I misunderstanding how one or more of these techniques should be used?

For what it's worth, we prefer to version control our .htaccess files and therefore don't put config items like these in httpd.conf or vhost etc.

Comment: Try using `/sitemap\.xml/i` instead of `m#^/sitemap\.xml$#i`.

Comment: Thanks @revo. That didn't work, but I'm starting to suspect that this has more to do with application flow than I originally thought. I'm pretty sure that `REQUEST_URI` is resolving to index.php while in .htaccess.

Answer (score 1):

```
<If "%{REQUEST_URI} == '/sitemap.xml'">
    Header set X-Robots-Tag "noindex"
</If>
```

or

```
<If "%{THE_REQUEST} =~ m#\s/sitemap\.xml# ">
     Header set X-Robots-Tag "noindex"
</If>
```

Comment: Thanks @dusan-bajic. That didn't work either, but I think this approach is doomed because of application flow. `REQUEST_URI` isn't resolving to sitemap.xml in .htaccess. I thought about deleting this question but am going to leave it up in case someone has a similar issue.

Comment: That could happen if there are rules that rewrite /sitemap.xml to index.php, but then try the other approach above